# Error: loading Role Definition List: could not find role 'Global Reader'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to assign ad role- global reader to service principal in terraform. I says role not found. Want to know whether I can assign ad role to service principal or only rbac role.

```
 Error: loading Role Definition List: could not find role 'Global Reader'
│ 
│   with module.infrastructure_cloud-scanner-app.azurerm_role_assignment.main["/subscriptions/aeca76e8-1861-4aed-b28a-b8c48923f89b"],
│   on ../../modules/infrastructure/cloud-scanner-app/main.tf line 49, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "main":
│   49: resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "main" {
```

Answer (score 0):

> Want to know whether I can assign ad role to service principal or only
> rbac role.

You can only assign [`Azure RBAC role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles).